# Environment variable inheritance in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, web-config, environment-variables

Many web.config settings in IIS that are set at the site level are inherited by applications from the parent site. I would like to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable at a root level in IIS so that each application that's deployed to that site will run under the appropriate environment, such as "Production".

When I configure the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable using the IIS Configuration Editor it's not visible in each application.

---

Here's where I'm setting it:

Section: `system.webServer/aspNetCore`

From: "`My.site.com/myApplication`"

---

Is there a way to configure an environment variable in IIS so that it cascades to all children?

Comment: Why not just use... you know... "environment variables" (the machine wide ones on OS level)

Comment: Thanks... you know.... for the "suggestion".

Comment: Well I was serious. When you want to define it at IIS root level, its essentially valid for every single ASP.NET Core application. You can as well set the variable machine wide which as the same effect

Comment: I went to Control Panel->System->Advanced->EnvironmentVariables and added it then restarted my App Pool but my application doesn't seem to be getting it. It's coming back with a 502.5 just like it does when the Environment Variable is not set. If I add it back to my application the 502.5 goes away.

Comment: Also, running SET from a command prompt shows it as being set.

Comment: Make sure your AppPool is set to load user profile (in advanced settings).

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisPratt. I tried that already.... I also rebooted the server. My app still seems to be ignoring all instances of the Environment variable except the one set in the web.config of the application itself.

Comment: Well, anything set in the web.config will take precedence, so make sure you remove that *first* before trying to load it from the system environment variables. Other than that, as long as your App Pool is loading the user profile, and you have the environment variable set with the correct name (`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`), it will work.

Comment: You need to use a tool like `setx` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx to set the environment variable at machine level (your clicks in Control Panel can easily go to your own profile wrongly).

Comment: By default, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is `Production`. make sure remove `environmentVariables` node in `web.config`. For `502.5` error, make sure you include valid `web.config` and configure `stdoutLogEnabled` to share us the error log.

Comment: LIke a dummy I was adding it to "User variables" rather than "System variables". Once I added it to the correct location I can access the Environment variable. Still never got it to work when set in IIS. I suspect it has something to do with the users that the processes are running under.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to set an environment variable server wide in IIS manager.

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. **Select the server** in the left sidebar.
3. **Open Configuration Editor** in the Management section.
4. **Select** the section **`system.webServer/aspNetCore`**.
5. **Open** the **environment variables** with clicking the **...** button in the respective field.
6. Add your environment variable(s).
7. Close the window.
8. **Click** on **Apply** in the right sidebar.

The environment variable(s) should now be inherited by the website or the application(s).

Comment: This is what I was shooting for but I can't get it to work. I set the variable but my app doesn't see it. I've even tested by logging all of the environment variables and my new one isn't there. I've also tried IISReset after adding it.

Comment: In your comments you say you have added the variables via Control Panel->System->Advanced->EnvironmentVariables. The way I described is differently it's done via the IIS Manager. Also remove your variable from the web.config as Chris said.

Comment: I've done both. I started out setting it in IIS. @Tseng suggested adding at the OS level, so I tried that as well. The result is the same. My application running in IIS only sees Environment variables that I add in IIS at the app level. It also sees all of the usual suspects, but not ones that I add.

Comment: If some sites already exist and then you try to add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  at top level will this environment variable still be inherited by existing sites?